# Facebook Javascript SDK and Safari - unexplained behaviour

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have looked at quite a few answers here with similar topic but couldn't find out what is causing this behaviour.

Here is my script:

```
 $("html").on("click",".fb",function(){
    var my_picture=$("#image_link_holder").attr('data-link');
    var file_id=$("#image_link_holder").attr('fileid');


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {


   FB.login(function(apiResponse){
    my_share="http://www.example.com/gallery.php-Q-event_id=<?php echo $event_id;?>";
    my_share=encodeURI(my_share+"-A-fb_cover-E-"+my_picture);

  FB.ui(
    {
    method:'feed',
    link: my_share, 
    display: 'touch',
    message: 'message',
    caption:'caption',
    name:"Name"

    })
}, {scope: ['publish_actions','email']});
```

This works perfectly in Chrome,FireFox,Edge,Android,Internet Explorer, but on Safari it just flashes a window and nothing else happens.

Looking with Safari for any console error or anything, but it's absolutely empty. When I press the button I see some network requests for 3 images from Facebook, but that's about it, it doesn't even fire or show any request to the:
`https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/` which happens in every other browser.

Can somebody shed some light in what I'm missing? It's driving me mental and of course it always have to be the beloved Apple with their "perfect" products.

The experience is reproduced in both Mac and iOS devices.
Safari version: 10.0.3
iOS: Simulator 10.1

This is how I load the SDK on the page:

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
      xfbml      : false,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });


   FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {});
    };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the IPad device to FB share properly, I had to turn off the settings for both "Block pop-ups" and "Open New Tabs in Background".[iPad Safari settings to share using Facebook API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HY5g.png)